# Posts made using the Javascript SDK feed dialog are small and truncated; don't match preview

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, feed, preview, truncated

I'm trying to update my `stream.publish` code to use the feed dialog in the javascript SDK, but the resulting facebook posts are small and ugly. More annoying is that the posts on facebook don't match the preview on my site.

Here's my code:

```
function facebook_publish_feed_story() {
  var publish = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'http://www.wikipedia.org/',
      picture: 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/63/Wikipedia-logo.png',
      name: 'Name of the link',
      caption: "A caption that's kind of long like this I'm going to write some more words"
      description: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas vitae augue sed urna fermentum vulputate. Nunc porttitor vestibulum vestibulum. Aliquam eget feugiat lectus. Duis ullamcorper sollicitudin nisi sit amet congue.'
    };

  FB.ui(publish, function(response) {
    //do something with response
  });
}
```

Here's the javascript pop-up with a preview of the post. This post looks totally fine and great to me:

[image: x]

And here's what it looks like once it's posted to facebook. Note that it's in a table with a dark background, and that the description is totally truncated, without even a "..." or "read more"

[image: x]

If this is "just the way it is", then that's fine and I'll give up, but if there's any way to fix this code, or use a different SDK call to make a more attractive and informative post, wouldn't that just be better for everybody?

Comment: you figure out a solution?  Is there a length limit?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution; I think it's a case of facebook exercising their right to display your information however they choose. It's frustrating that the preview doesn't match the final post, but since we're using their SDK, we're beholden to that. See below for a hint that the caption might hold more content than the description. Unfortunately I don't think there's even a character-count limit, as it depends on the amount of space; likely you're limited to two lines.

Comment: I think it is space related ... match the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same here, the post becomes truncated. I noticed that this issue has started recently. My 'solution' was to put the text in the caption value instead of description. It seems that the caption can contain more characters than the description.

Comment: Accepting this as it doesn't appear that there's a better way, or that I'll be receiving any more responses...Still not happy about it.

Comment: I don't think there's any difference posting in description or in caption. This is happening with me in iOS SDK and I've just tried both keys and got exact same result.